# Calculate percentage of records by category

Tags: sql

I have a table named author with authorId(PK), firstname.  A second table named article with  articleID(PK), articleTitle, articleText, authorId(FK), categoryId(FK). A third table named category with categryId(PK), categoryText.

How can I get the percentage of articles of a specific categoryText that an author wrote using sql?

Comment: We need to see some effort from your side before we can jump in with the answer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: ErikE what I have in mind till now is to create a query :select count(articles) from articles but I don't know how to set up the WHERE in order to "connect" the tables(article and category) and specify that I need a certain category.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name I am using Derby as DBMS

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` and `groupby` and aggregate function called `count`. You might know then already. Then, notice that the `%` is just the number of "hits" divided by the number of "all things" (times 100 for readability).

Hence, a sketch of two queries for that would look like:

```
Select count(*) from FooTable;
```

write the result to some variable like @totalCount, and then

```
-- watch out for the division; the value divided must be floating-point or you'll get all zeroes
Select categoryName, 100.0*count(*)/@totalCount
from FooTable
group by categoryName
```

If your sql dialect permits and if you like to, you can then glue that together into one query, like:

```
select categoryName, 100.0*hits/allcount
from
(
    Select
        categoryName,
        count(*) as hits
    from FooTable
    group by categoryName
) as subq
cross join
(
    Select
        count(*) as allcount
    from FooTable
) as allstats
```

The above is OK in t-SQL on MsSqlServer. However, it runs the aggregation twice (once for hitcounts, once for alllcount). The 'allcount' is not really necessary. Since once you have hitcounts, you may want to calculate the total count and percentages on the fly in the view.

edit: the same even shorter

```
Select
    categoryName,
    count(*) * 100.0 / ( Select count(*) as allcount from FooTable)
from FooTable
group by categoryName
```